# Is it possible to use Android 2.2 on Eclipse current version?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to use Android 2.2 on Eclipse current version?
And Is it working properly on Eclipse current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Eclipse 3.6.1 with ADT 0.9.9. All android versions from 1.5 to 2.2 work like a charm.

Comment: What about current version of android (2.2) ?

Comment: I got the following error on error log,

"conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1"



How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [Eclipse ADT Plugin installation instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), there are known problems with the ADT plugin under the latest version of Eclipse (3.6).

> **Caution:** There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with
>   Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until
>   further notice.

It might work OK for you, but there can be certain problems as well. One known issue is that you might experience lag when accessing the intellisense menu.

Comment: There are fixes for the menu. It involves putting android source into the sdk folder

Comment: @Falmarri: That's interesting. Could you perhaps provide a link to a bit more detailed explanation of this, as I didn't follow your comment 100%?

Comment: I used netbeans for developing all my mobile applications. so i dont knw how about eclipse. so which version of eclipse is best for android developing?